# Spring performance interceptor not logging with log4j2

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, aop, log4j2, pointcut

I have used spring aop t to log time of service execution but it's not logging. i am not getting any exception as well.
help me to solve this issue whether it's problem in log4j2 configuration or it's wrong with point cut expression.

Following is my application-context.xml

```
<bean id="perfMonitor"
        class="org.springframework.aop.interceptor.PerformanceMonitorInterceptor">

    </bean>
    <aop:config proxy-target-class="true">

        <aop:pointcut id="allServiceMethods" expression="execution(* com.lfr.services..*.*(..))" 
            /> 
        <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="allServiceMethods" advice-ref="perfMonitor"
            order="1" />

    </aop:config>
```

following is my log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="debug">
    <appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %level - %m%n%ex%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="log4jdbc_file" fileName="d:/logs/log4jdbc21.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %level - %m%n%ex%n" />
        </File>
    </appenders>
    <loggers>

        <logger name="log4jdbc.log4j2" level="info" additivity="false">
            <MarkerFilter marker="LOG4JDBC_NON_STATEMENT" onMatch="DENY"
                onMismatch="NEUTRAL" />
            <appender-ref ref="log4jdbc_file" />

        </logger>


        <logger
            name="org.springframework.aop.interceptor.PerformanceMonitorInterceptor"
            level="trace">

            <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        </logger>


        <root level="trace">
            <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        </root>

    </loggers>

</configuration>
```

Comment: not an answer you're looking for, but you can use spring mvc interceptors for the job check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022108/is-spring-handlerinterceptoradapter-posthandle-guaranteed