# Spring Boot interceptor with @PostConstruct - @Autowired not retained

Tags: spring-boot

Right to the problem:  my `@Autowired` data and anything I set in my `@PostConstruct` method is not retained.  I might be misunderstanding the bean lifecycle in this case.

Here is my class:

```
@Component
public class HeaderInspector implements HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HeaderInspector.class);

  @Autowired
  private ConfigurationService configuration;

  @Autowired
  private WaffleHeaderService waffleHeader;

  private String logPrefix;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    logPrefix = configuration.getLogPrefix("WaffleHeader");
  }

  @Override
  public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    // logs:  "null Intercept"
    LOGGER.trace(logPrefix + " Intercept");

    // !!! NullPointException !!!
    return waffleHeader.accept(request);
  }
}
```

I marked the two problem areas with comments.

Comment: 5 cents: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022108/is-spring-handlerinterceptoradapter-posthandle-guaranteed

Comment: `@Autowired` properties cannot be `null`... They can only be `null` if you are constructing instances yourself (which makes them non-spring managed beans) or if you are using them in a context which doesn't have annotation processing enabled. Generally it is the first of the 2 by not making it a spring managed bean. I guess you have a `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` overriden the `addInterceptors` method and inside that method do `registry.addInterceptor(new HeaderInspector())`.